# How to get target's version by Ruby (or Xcodeproj)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods, xcodeproj

How to get target's version(The version of you APP) in `Ruby` or [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj)?

I have tried `sdk_version` in `AbstractTarget` with Xcodeproj, But it returns nil.

If `Xcodeproj` doesn't support it. How to get the version by `Ruby`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in Ruby using the [plist](https://rubygems.org/gems/plist) gem, like this:

```
require 'plist'
info = Plist.parse_xml('path/to/Info.plist')
puts info["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
puts info["CFBundleVersion"]
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

- `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString")` should give you version number
- `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion")` should give you build number

Comment: Is this Swift code? Question is how to get the app version in Ruby.

Comment: Yes it is swift code. Try it in your app delegate and print the result to check quickly.