# How to get the minimum deployment target in the xcode project

Tags: ios, ruby

I want to retrieve the minimum deployment target in the xcode project.
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.2;
I wanted to check whether the version is 13.2 or lesser.
Is there any way or any command which returns the deployment target.
I want to read it from the ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the target version by below code and perform your desired action

**In Swift:**

```
    if #available(iOS 13.2, *) {
        // your code for iOS 13.2 or above versions
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions or your code for earlier versions
    }
```

**In Objective C:**

```
    if (@available(iOS 13.2, *)) {
        // your code for iOS 13.2 or above versions
     } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions or your code for earlier versions
     }
```

**In Ruby:**

Using the plist gem, like this:

```
require 'plist'
info = Plist.parse_xml('path/to/Info.plist')
puts info["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
puts info["CFBundleVersion"]
```

Use this reference: [How to get target's version by Ruby (or Xcodeproj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269133/how-to-get-targets-version-by-ruby-or-xcodeproj)

also, https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/XCConfigurationList

Comment: I am trying to read ios applications from the ruby code for some tasks. So i want to get the deployment version from the ruby code. Thanks

Comment: xcodeproj_file = File.read(location + '/*.xcodeproj' + XCODE_PROJECT_FILE_NAME)
I am trying to read the ios application project file like this and trying to get the deployment version from this file. Earlier i was thinking to read line by line and try to match IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET and get the version but now i want to get that version without reading line by line.

Comment: I don't know about Ruby but Why you need to find the deployment target. And the above concept you said also work. You can simply set the minimum target version in code.

Comment: I am building an app in my organisation which is in ruby which checks the ios applications deployment versions and if it is less than 13.2 i am failing the scenario. Something for other type of applications too. So i wanted it to be in ruby. Thanks

Comment: @Mahant Please check. Might be it helps you.

Comment: Here's a question that has ruby vs. the project file format -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834668/ruby-modify-project-pbxproj